# Keep textview content in listview scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I have read about this confusing material, "listview scrolling lost content" and It made me frustrated. So I decide to ask here. Here is what I need:

```
(TextItems)  (TextValue)
Item1            0 
Item2            0
Item3            0
// after input custom edittext dialog, It must be:
Item1            3
Item2            8
Item3            5
```

But, after I scroll down my screen(3 items isnot displayed on screen) then sroll up again, those item values is back to 0. Here is my Main.java:

```
String[] items = {"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4",..,"Item30"};

final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listItems); 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new LVAdapter(this, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = Main.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
                alert.setView(v);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editInput);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textValue); // for giving value on each Items
                        tv.setText(userInput.getText());
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog al = alert.create();
                al.show();
            }
        });
```

Then, its my LVAdapter.java

```
public class LVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final String[] val;

public LVAdapter(Context context, String[] val) {
    super(context, R.layout.detail_item, val);
    this.context = context;
    this.val = val;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_item, parent, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textItems); //for storing Item1, Item2, .., etc.
    tv.setText(val[position]);

    return v;
}
```

Main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" >
</ListView>
```

And Its main_items.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textItems"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!-- I need to set this textView based on users input -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textValue"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="0"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I am. Stack in how to implement "what is it called" for keeping my value, even I srolling my screen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to notify your adapter after changing your dataset.

Comment: Because android recycle the view of list items. You need to store your data to list you pass in your adapter for saving the data.

Comment: @sanatshukla I failed to implement it. Could you give me the code.

Comment: Wait i will give you example for that

Comment: @Alca check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set entered value to list or array you passed to your adapter.

Like this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = Main.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
                alert.setView(v);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editInput);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       // Don't set text view item here
                       // Here you need to set value to your array or list which you passed to adapter for listview
                       items[position] = userInput.getText().toString();
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Use this for reflects the entered value
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog al = alert.create();
                al.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Mark as correct answer dear if this answer resolved your problem ;)

Comment: Do I need to modify my getView methode..?

Comment: position is the index or position you clicked on list and items is your array. If you want to set value to your clicked list item then you need to set value at that position. items[position] is the position in array where u want to change your data.

Comment: No you don't need to change anything other than above code. Just set your entered text to your array and notify adapter for reflect the change in listview.

Comment: But it is recommended to use a ViewHolder pattern like Amsheer said.

Comment: That was great.. but I meant, I dont want to change textViewItem which is contains Item[].. I need to change textViewValue.. Does it mean that I must define new variable for the textViewValue?

Comment: You set TextView value using the items[]. So if you want to change the TextView value then you need to change items[] value also.

Comment: Oh sorry.. In the Main.java I set textView for value, but In LVAdapter I set textView for items. I want to keep Items[] still on textViewItems and just change textViewValues.

Comment: There are 2 TextVIew, (TextItem contains Items[] which is as the list item) and (TextValue contains each of item value from userInput dialog). Actually I just need to change TextValue keep on the screen, even I scroll it.

Comment: How can someone understand your situation dear. Please put your xml of listview row for that.

Comment: @sanatshukla I just added my xml. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alca you need to create ViewObject which contain getter and setter for your two TextView. Then Create List<ViewObjectClass> with your ViewObject class. Then set your text in Adapter.

Comment: @sanatshukla thanks for your help. Finally I got it. :D

Answer (score 1):

ListView is recycling its child views and does not save your input automatically. This means that you have to do the dirty work yourself. First save the input and then retrieve it and display it in the correct place.
There are some answers on stack you can check out but anyway here is a code I used:

```
    public class ArrayListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<Product> productlist= null;
    private  Activity context=null;


    public ArrayListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Product> objects) {
        this.productlist= objects;
        this.context=context;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView textvw;
        EditText edittx;
        int ref;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(productlist!=null&&productlist.size()>0)
            return productlist.size();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView==null){
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.textvw =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.edittx =(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ref=position;
        holder.textvw.setText(productlist.get(position).name);
        holder.edittx.setText(productlist.get(position).quantity);

        holder.edittx.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                productlist.get(holder.ref).quantity= s.toString();
productlist.get(holder.ref).quantity);
productlist.get(holder.ref+1).quantity );


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Both of them is textview, so is it possible to implement addTextChangedListener to set the textviews value?

Comment: I didn't try it but I think that it is possible. I've seen some answers where people used onFocusChange (I think that's the name of the method). I prefer using addTextChangedListener  but you could also try onFocusChange. If they don't work you can try changing your textview to edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your getView method. You need to modify your getView like this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_item, parent, false);
            holder. tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textItems); 
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        holder. tv.setText(val[position]);

        return v;
    }
```

Also add holder class

```
class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
    }
```

Comment: he is not updating his dataset in the list item click. changing the getview method will not work i think.

Comment: What i mean was when the listview get recycling the values are reset need to handle it. It may solve the issue i guess

Comment: By using ViewHolder we can easily access each view without the need for the look-up (findViewById()). But I think the values set in each components will not be held in ViewHolder.

Comment: Why each components will not be held in ViewHolder?

Comment: each components (Views) will. but the values set in each components wont.

Comment: Exactly because the reason of recycling this is happening. This will work.

Comment: @Amsheer Now, I understand about how to use it, thanks for your contribution. :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a Hashmap of views and add your listview item views in it, and on scrolling if your item is already present in hashmap then retrieve that item from hashmap. This will not result in your content lost.

```
HashMap<Integer, View> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, View>();


public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
 {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (hashMap.containsKey(position)) {
        return hashMap.get(position);
    }
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_item, null);

    // set tag and put views in hashmap
    view.setTag(holder);
    hashMap.put(position, view);

    return view;
}
```

Hope this will work...... Thank You

Comment: How could I add this line... ?
final ViewHolder holder;

Comment: public class ViewHolder{
//here you u will declare the views of the detail_item layout
}