# When I scroll the listview the textview get its default value 0

Tags: java, android

I have two button increase and decrease and one textview. When I click on increase button the value in the textview is increases and vice versa but when I scroll the listview its get its default value 0. How can I resolve this?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mImgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_image);
            viewHolder.mTvItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            viewHolder.mTvItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_price);
            viewHolder.mTvNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            viewHolder.mBtnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            viewHolder.mBtnMinus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
            viewHolder.mImgDelete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_del);
            viewHolder.mUniqueKey = String.valueOf(position);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setTag(viewHolder);

        viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("0");
        viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewHolder tagHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

                int mValue = Integer.parseInt(tagHolder.mTvNumber.getText().toString().trim());
                mValue++;
                tagHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + mValue);    
        });

        viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ViewHolder tagHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    int mValue = Integer.parseInt(tagHolder.mTvNumber.getText().toString());
                    if (mValue > 0) {
                        mValue--;
                        tagHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + mValue);
                    }

        });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.mTvItemName.setText(pojoCart.getmItemName());
        viewHolder.mTvItemPrice.setText(pojoCart.getmItemPrice());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: `viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("0");` replace zero with latest value which you must be ideally retrieving every time from your POJO class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the value to PojoCart class and retrieve value from it every time just as you are getting itemName and itemPrice. So create an integer quantity in PojoCart class and in the adapter's getView method :

```
PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) getItem(position);
viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setTag(pojoCart);
viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setTag(pojoCart);
if(pojoCart.getQuantity() > 0)
{
   viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText(""+pojoCart.getQuantity());
}
else
{
   viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText(""+0);
}
viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) v.getTag();
            int mValue = pojoCart.getQuantity();
            mValue++;
            tagHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + mValue);
            pojoCart.setQuantity(mValue)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
};
```

Comment: how can i save the value in the pojo class. can u describe me please !

Comment: by your code the textview not getting default value but value is assign multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save value of textview.
As listview recreate views on scroll it takes default
Just take model class and save values by position

Comment: how can i save the value of the texview . can you tell me. please

Answer (score 0):

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update values in listview when data changes

Comment: i already use it. but the problem is when the value in the textview is 5 and i scroll the listview . its getting default value 0.

Comment: Check this question's accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934216/keep-textview-content-in-listview-scrolling and check out this accepted answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780180/text-values-are-changed-in-customized-listview-when-scroll-the-listview-in-andro

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the number in each list item for example use this function to change the value of the list item's number:

```
List<Integer> mList = new ArrayList<>(LIST_SIZE);

int changeNumber(int position, int value){
    mList.get(position) += value;
    return mList.get(position);
}
```

u can use this function like:

```
viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder tagHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            int mValue = Integer.parseInt(tagHolder.mTvNumber.getText().toString().trim());
            tagHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + changeNumber(position,1);    
    });

    viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewHolder tagHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                int mValue = Integer.parseInt(tagHolder.mTvNumber.getText().toString());
                if (mValue > 0) {
                    tagHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + changeNumber(position,-1);
                }

    });
```